# raw_input() with "if....in.." statements

Tags: python, if-statement, plist, raw-input

I'm trying to write a little game that requires input from the user.

```
while True:
    x = raw_input("\n> ")

    if x in ["Susan", "Foreman"] and not grand_name: 
        print "The button glows! You have guessed the password! You can press the button now"
        grand_name = True
    elif x in ["Press", "press", "button"] and not grand_name:
        print "You have to guess the password first!"
    elif x in ["Press", "press", "button"] and grand_name:
        print "The TARDIS materializes around the Doctor! He has been freed from a gaseous monster!"
        end()
    else:
        print "Try Again."
```

I want to make it so the user can type "press the button" or "I press the button" to satisfy the desired elif statements, as opposed to them having to type exactly the list's objects. I just want the statement to run if the word itself is anywhere in their input. Is there a way that Python can recognize if the input contains the word in the list without typing exactly the word? I hope that makes sense. This is my first question I've asked, so I'm still learning. Thanks.

I tried using any() like in the example below, but it returns an error "global name w is not defined"

while True:
        x = raw_input("\n> ")
        opt1 = ["Susan", "Foreman"]
        opt2 = ["Press", "press", "button"]

```
    if any(z in x for z in opt1): 
        print "The button glows! You have guessed the password! You can press the button now"
        grand_name = True
    elif any(w in x for w in opt2) and not grand_name:
        print "You have to guess the password first!"
    elif any(w in x for x in opt2) and grand_name:
        print "The TARDIS materializes around the Doctor! He has been freed from a gaseous monster!"
        end()
    else:
        print "Try Again."
```

Comment: I think you forgot to actually ask your first question.  :)  See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/03/15/1883515.aspx

Comment: haha wow sorry. Ok here it goes: Is there a way that Python can recognize if the input contains the word in the list without typing exactly the word? *sorry, have mercy on me*

Answer (score 0):

You mean `if "press" in x.lower() or "button" in x.lower()` ?

```
>>> "press" in "some sentence with the word press in it"
True

>>> words = ["press","button","otherword"]
>>> any(w in "aaa press bbb" for w in words)
True
>>> any(w in "aaa button bbb" for w in words)
True
>>> any(w in "aaa bbb" for w in words)
False
```

Comment: So for multiple words I would just use a bunch of "or" statements?

Comment: yes, or put them in a list and use a loop/list comprehension. I updated the code with an example of that.

Comment: I did that and got an error saying that "global name w isn't defined".  this is so frustrating.

Comment: What is your python version? Try `any([w in "aaa bbb" for w in words])` (with brackets).